# Why and how nullable Int types can be compared for equality but can't be compared for greater/less?

Tags: android, kotlin, null

Sorry for the easy question but.. Why Int/Long/Double, etc.. can be compared with the == inside an if statement but when trying to compare with > or < the compiler refuse to it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you can compare `null == null` and it will return true or `null == 1` and it will return false. But what do you think about `null < 1`? should it return true or false?

Comment: I understand you, but how does the compiler know that? According to what he decided which method is valid and which is not?

Comment: You can try something like this: a?.compareTo(1). Or write your own custom extension, like: fun Int.greaterThan(val other: Int) = this != null && this > other

Comment: @Alex.Marynovskyi, thanks mate, but i more interesting to understand how the compiler "is thinking", what it's logic say than finding an alternative way, although you solution is great :)

Comment: @Eitanos30, you're welcome. I suppose we can't do this since null doesn't have a type. It's just null, nothing. You can't expect nothing to be greater or equal to something

Comment: `a == b` translated to `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#equals, but for comparison operators it's not obvious what we should do if there are nullable objects

Comment: @IR42, thank for the answer and also for the reference. Can you please tell me why it is written b===null and not b==null. I tried to understand it from the link but didn't succeeded. I know the === check equality of reference but the case of null isn't clear for me. Now i confuse anytime i need to check a reference against null if to check it with *==* or with *===*

Comment: "Note that there's no point in optimizing your code when comparing to null explicitly: a == null will be automatically translated to a === null." https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: ``===`` means referential equality, i.e. literally the same object in memory, whereas ``==`` just means ``is equal to`` which could be the same object, or it could be two different instances that return ``true`` for ``a.equals(b)``. As far as I'm aware, there's only one instance of ``null`` anyway (probably why it gets translated to ``===``!)

Answer (score 1):

Equality, just like function types, is a language feature, so *it just works* to use it on a nullable object. When you try to follow the function call to the source code, it just takes you to `Any.equals`, even though that shouldn't be callable from a nullable if following the rules of operator functions.

You'll also notice that none of the functions for `Any` have their implementations shown in the source code, even though they are not abstract, because `Any` is special. A lot of the functionality of the primitive classes is also special, although their function signatures are shown in the source code.

If you wanted to write your own function that works on nullable types, you would define it as an extension function with nullable receiver. For example:

```
fun MyClass?.doSomething() {
    if (this == null) {
        println("is null")
    } else {
        println("Hello from $this")
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't know that in declaration of function I can add a question mark. So i can add king of: Int?.compareTo extension method?